# How to import types from `material-ui`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am working on a `react` app with `material-ui` in `typescript`. I wonder where I can find all types definition for `material` component. I have tried to install `@types/material-ui` but it doesn't work well. See below example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
import { SvgIconProps } from "material-ui";

export const Logo = (props: SvgIconProps) => (
  <SvgIcon {...props}>
    <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" />
  </SvgIcon>
);
```

I got below error on compilation:

```
Type '{ children: Element; color?: string | undefined; hoverColor?: string | undefined; onMouseEnter?: ((event: MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined; onMouseLeave?: ((event: MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined; ... 413 more ...; ref?: string | ... 3 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'SvgIconProps'.
  Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | "default" | "disabled" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary" | "action" | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | "default" | "disabled" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary" | "action" | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific props can be imported material UI itself.

For `SvgIcon` component from the question, the [Prop Typing](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8523b1578616a3c952694eb0a15d242380c1e731/packages/material-ui/src/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.d.ts) can be imported with:

```
import SvgIcon, { SvgIconProps } from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work well. I have updated my question with the error message I got

Comment: @ZhaoYi From the recent version, the typings are bundled with material ui package itself, it seems these `@types` are out of date. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

In material-ui v5 (mui) it can be imported like so:

```
import { SvgIconProps } from '@mui/material';
```